# Latitude and Longitude values in GeoGraphics Image

Tags: geography, geographics

I want to plot the Sicily with a lat/lon grid and respective values. This is what I've done so far:

```
latRange = Range[36.61, 38.36, 0.5];
lonRange = Range[12.34, 15.70, 0.5];
exampleMap = GeoGraphics[
  {
   GeoStyling["ReliefMap"],
   Polygon[Entity["Island", "Sicily"]]
   },
  GeoGridLines -> {
    latRange,
    lonRange
    },
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> 700
  ]
```

[image: Sicily]

The problem is that frame ticks does not correspond to correct values of latitude and longitude (I want also to rotate the map but maybe it's better to ask in another question); latitude labels are wrong, as we can see from Google Earth for example:

[image]

Latitude values that I've set in fact are in a different range. Longitude lines seem correct but I'm not sure at this point.

How I can set the frame ticks with correct values of latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 2):

**Use `GeoProjection->None`:**

```
latRange = Range[36.61, 38.36, 0.5];
lonRange = Range[12.34, 15.70, 0.5];
exampleMap = 
 GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["ReliefMap"], 
   Polygon[Entity["Island", "Sicily"]]}, 
  GeoGridLines -> {latRange, lonRange}, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 700, GeoProjection -> None
  , FrameTicks -> {{latRange, None}, {lonRange, None}}
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to take into account the projection? Because in my use case I need to create those map with different projections, and draw the corresponding lat/lon lines with correct frame ticks...

Comment: Correct display of lat/lon should not be dependent on the projection. I would say it is likely a bug; but wait for a while and someone else might have a better explanation or workaround.